# pfSense OpenVPN Routing to Sever LAN

Tags: routing, openvpn, pfsense, gateway

I'm trying to get my OpenVPN server to route traffic from clients to the server's LAN.

My setup is as follows:

pfSense box at 10.1.1.1

Other servers on the LAN at 10.1.10.0/24 (with DNS server at 10.1.10.51)

Office computers at 10.1.11.0/24

OpenVPN with tunnel network at 10.1.13.0/24

I can't for the life of me get the OpenVPN clients to reach 10.1.10.0

Advanced options for OpenVPN:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"; 
push "route 10.1.10.0 255.255.255.0"; 
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.1.10.51";
```

I tried adding a route on the pfsense box

```
route add -net 10.1.13.0/24 gw 10.1.1.1
```

but that didn't do it. Maybe I misunderstand how this routing thing should work.

As far as I can tell, the firewall isn't blocking anything.

What should I add to the IPv4 Local Network/s field for the VPN? It's blank at the moment, but even when it was 10.1.0.0/16, this didn't work.

I'm a bit clueless when it comes to networking. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is pfsense running your openvpn process? Can the 10.1.10.0/24 machines reach the pfsense machine? Does the default route for 10.1.10.0/24 pass through pfsense (10.1.1.1) or have you set up an explicit route for 10.1.13.0/24 for machines on 10.1.10.0/24 with gateway of the openvpn server?

Comment: The client can connect and routes all traffic through the VPN. All the machines on 10.1.10.0/24 use the pfsense machine as the default route.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 local network should be 10.1.10.0/24 if you want your clients to reach 10.1.10.x. Don't use static routes for the networks that are directly connected to an interface of your pfsense box. If your clients are using win7 then "Run as administrator" your openvpn client.